# show admin which user clicked a particular button

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, onclick, admin

I want to create interaction between users and site admin in real time so i need suggestion on how to do it.
I have 3 buttons in my page, when a user clicks on one of the 3 buttons admin should know which user clicked that particular button

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" value="1" />
<input type="button" value="2" />
<input type="button" value="3" />
</body>
</html>
```

When a user clicks on button 1 the admin should receive the details of user who clicked the button

I'm looking for good suggestion on how to accomplish this thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add other node part as well that u tried

Comment: @Ritchie sorry for that, i haven't added any thing till now but based on suggestions i get i'm going to add but i'm thinking to use node js for this

Comment: You can read more on  socket.io

Comment: @Ritchie can i accomplish this with admin and users chat application